# How to increase the TextArea length in asp.net webform using bootstrap

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, web-applications

I have a code like this in my aspx page:

```
<div class="container">

        <h3 class="my-5 h2">Tasks List</h3>


        <div class="form-group w-75">
                <label for="lastmonth">Enter Tasks:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="lastmonth" rows="7"></textarea>
          </div>

    </div>
```

But the text area does not seem to change even if I give  or .I want to increase the textbox to occupy 3/4th of my page. Right now, it is only 1/4th. I even did the below change in my Site.css but it doesnt seem to change.

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve by setting cols and rows as attributes instead of using bootstrap

Try this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="lastmonth" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

I am attaching the screenshot for your reference:

[image]